# How to work and compile efficiently in a multi-file project in Texworks?

Tags: texworks, subfiles

I use Texworks on a multi-file project linked to each other through a master file. It is quite tedious to modify a subfile, save, change window to master file and then compile.

Is it possible to configure the software to link the compile button to the master file so that I can compile directly from the sub-file window?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `!TeX root=mainfile.tex`.

Comment: In Texmaker you can easily define a master document via a menu entry.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, consider asking about what is unclear. If it does, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use magical comments just as `!TeX root=mainfile.tex` with relative path as first line of your subfile.

Let's say you have the following document tree:

```
thesis.tex
chapters/
- chapone.tex
- chaptwo.tex
```

Then your `chapone.tex` (which is `\input` or `\include`d in `thesis.tex`) would start with:

```
%!TeX root=../thesis.tex
% your document here
```

Comment: I got: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
I used !TEX root = C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\phd2\thesis.tex

Comment: @Carlos You cannot use `\ ` as LaTeX assumes a command. That's why I talked about relative paths. I'll add an example.

Comment: Well, that's not a question of relative or absolute paths is it, it's a question of using forward slash instead of backslash in the path.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know, but it's usually easier to use relative paths. But I'm also too used to Linux these days.

Comment: Sure, but your comment said (basically) "you can't use backslash, that's why I said relative paths".  Anyways, after rereading,  the lack of a `%` seems to be the cause of the OPs error.

Comment: The above example didn't work for me, instead I had to write `!TeX` as `!TEX`